# Hacer una busqueda exacta en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Muy buenas tardes comunidad

Me gustaría que porfa me ayudaran con la siguiente cuestión. Tengo el siguiente código que funciona bien pero trae mas de un registro porque la coincidencia no es exacta

```
      $referencia = $_POST['referencia'];

      $sql = "SELECT referencia, nombre_referencia FROM producto WHERE multi = (SELECT multi FROM producto WHERE referencia = :referencia )";
      $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $result = $query->execute(['referencia' => $referencia]);

      if ($result) {
        while ($data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
          $arreglo["data"][] = $data;
      } else
        echo '2';

      echo json_encode(utf8ize($arreglo), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }

La búsqueda la hace bien, pero trae mas de un dato ya que la condición no es exacta, en la referencia tengo un 20019 y un 20019-1

Muchas gracias por la valiosa ayuda
```

Comment: Usa `LIMIT 1` y te devolverá el primero unicamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, quedo perfecto